# Define optional self-referencing one-many relationship with Fluent Api

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.3

```
public class Attribute
{
    [Key]
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ValueAttributeId { get; set; }
    public Attribute ValueAttribute { get; set; }

    public IList<Attribute> ValueAttributes { get; set; }
}

  modelBuilder.Entity<Attribute>()
     .HasOptional(a => a.ValueAttribute)
     .WithMany(a => a.ValueAttributes)
     .HasForeignKey(a => a.ValueAttributeId);
```

> \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationType: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'Attribute_ValueAttribute_Target' in relationship 'Attribute_ValueAttribute'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.

Aaaaahhhh.....

Comment: public int ? ValueAttributeId { get; set; }

Comment: As an aside - part of the benefit of using EFCF is that you don't need to decorate your POCOs with attributes like `[Key]` or `[Required]`.

Comment: Yes... then I could avoid referencing EF from my domain.

Comment: another aside, you'll be wanting to mark those properties up with the `virtual` keyword.

Comment: I'm not a fan of lazy loading. ;) Too great a chance of unwanted data being loaded and loaded inefficiently.

Comment: @Yuck On second thoughts I think its a good thing to annotate entities with [Key] and [Required] and not push this information down to the data access layer. They're data access technology agnostic aren't they (they're defined in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and not EntityFramework)? ASP.net MVC auto validation even reads [Required].

Comment: You can post your first comment as an answer and accept it, just to finish this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public int ? ValueAttributeId { get; set; }
```

... the property needed to be null-able.